# Import data from text file with multiple conditions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse this text file using Pandas data frame. 
The text file is in this particular format:

```
Name: Tom 
Gender: Male

Books:
The problem of Pain 
The reason for God: belief in an age of skepticism
```

My code so far to import the data is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=":|\n", engine='python', index_col=0)
print df
```

The output I got is:

```
Name                     Tom   
Gender                   Male
Books                    NaN
The problem of Pain      NaN
The reason for God       belief in an age of skepticism
```

How should I change the code such that the output I get will be: (edited output)

```
Name     Gender    Books
Tom      Male      The problem of Pain, The reason for God: belief in an age of skepticism
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I use is simple: `regex`.

```
import os, re
import pandas as pd


# List out the all files in dir that ends with .txt
files = [file for file in os.listdir(PROFILES) if file.endswith(".txt")]

HEADERS = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Books']
DATA = []  # create the empty list to store profiles

for file in files:  # iterate over each file
    filename = PROFILES + file  # full path name of the data files

    text_file = open(filename, "r")  # open the file
    lines = text_file.read()  # read the file in memory
    text_file.close()  # close the file

    ###############################################################
    # Regex to filter out all the column header and row data. ####
    # Odd Number == Header, Even Number == Data ##################
    ###############################################################

    books = re."(Name):(.*)\n+(Gender):(.*)\n+(Books):((?<=Books:)\D+)",lines)

    # append data into DATA list
    DATA.append([books.group(i).strip() for i in range(len(books.groups()) + 1) if not i % 2 and i != 0])

profilesDF = pd.DataFrame(DATA, columns=HEADERS) # create the dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things. You can use `enumerate()`, and use an `if` statement:, I used a text file named `test.txt` in the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {}
value_list = []
for index, text in enumerate(open('test.txt', "r")):
    if index < 2:
        d[text.split(':')[0]] = text.split(':')[1].rstrip('\n')
    elif index ==2:
        value = text.split(':')[0]
    else:
        value_list.append(text.rstrip('\n'))
d[value] = [value_list]
df = pd.DataFrame.(d)
```

Instead you can use `readlines()` and then slice through each line to get and populate the `dictionary` and then create a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd:
text_file = open('test.txt', "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
d = {}
d[lines[0:1][0].split(':')[0]] = lines[0:1][0].split(':')[1].rstrip('\n')
d[lines[1:2][0].split(':')[0]] = lines[1:2][0].split(':')[1].rstrip('\n')
d[lines[2:3][0].split(':')[0]] = [lines[3:]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help. I understand how it is done. But what if the format is change to the above? How to I format it such that pandas can parse this in.

Comment: @z.yea edited my code, remove the `.T` transpose and make a book values into a list. If it helps you can accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help and it really gave me the idea on how to construct the data. However, I didnt use your method but its did greatly help me to move on.
I uses regex to extract the data in the file and append it to an empty list. Then cast it to pandas data frame